# Under Construction page in Partner Community

Tags: community, force.com-sites

I have a partner community with custom pages for login, home, and error.
I want to also assign a custom VF page to the Under Construction scenario.
How can I do it? 
In the Site detail page I see other error pages I can customise but not this one

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to change it, even if you customize the default UnderConstruction page I believe it won't take the effect because declarative assigment do not change the result.

Please refer following link this might help you for better understanding.
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BV1QIAW